# What are the brain structures directly on top of the brain stem?

Tags: human-biology, human-anatomy, brain, neuroanatomy

I have been trying to learn the anatomy of the brain, and some information on their functions, through an iPad app called [3D Brain](https://itunes.apple.com/az/app/3d-brain/id331399332?mt=8).  Whilst going through the different parts, I have noticed that one area doesn’t seem to be mentioned.

If you look at the image below, you get the brain stem (colour highlighted and labelled).

[image: Brain Stem]

Going from the brain stem upwards, I am then trying to identify the structures in medium grey which sit on top of the midbrain.

I have seen that the bulbous areas left and right are the basal ganglia.

[image: Basal Ganglia]

What are the rest of the structures?  I would like to know what all the mid grey structures are in the first image, but I am especially curious to know what I have drawn around below.

[image: curious areas of the brain]

Comment: Can I ask why I am getting downvoted?

Comment: I'm not one of the downvotes, but I think this question comes off as a bit under-researched and poorly motivated, while also being quite broad. Basically this approach to studying the brain doesn't make a lot of sense, and there are lots of sources besides this app to learn basic brain anatomy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking at *many* structures in this area.

The region directly above the midbrain is the [**diencephalon**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diencephalon) (meaning "across + brain"). From inferior to superior it's composed of the [**hypothalamus**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypothalamus), [**thalamus**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thalamus), and structures that developed from a developmental region referred to as the [**epithalamus**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epithalamus) that include the [**pineal gland**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pineal_gland), [**habenular trigone**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Habenular_trigone), and [**choroid plexus**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choroid_plexus). Between the hemispheres of the thalamus/hypothalmus lies the [**third ventricle**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_ventricle) (which may be "bridged" by a structure called the [**interthalamic adhesion**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interthalamic_adhesion)).

Of each of these structures, **only the thalamus and hypothalamus are truly visible from your images** -- with the hypothalamus articulating with the midbrain and the thalamus emerging superior and slightly lateral to he hypothalamus. **The following structures are also visible in your image:**

The most inferior structure you see is the [**pituitary gland**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pituitary_gland), while the "X" shaped structure superior to it is the [**optic chiasm**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optic_chiasm) with cut [**optic nerves**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optic_nerve) anteriorly and [**optic tracts**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optic_tract) continuing posteriorly out of view. 
It's not entirely clear, but I believe the two protruding structures posterior to the pituitary are the paired [**oculomotor nerves**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oculomotor_nerve). 
Finally, the two long ribbon-like structures that extend anteriorly are the [**olfactory tracts**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olfactory_tract) of [**cranial nerve I**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cranial_nerves#Smell_(I)) that terminate anteriorly in [**optic bulbs**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olfactory_bulb).

[image]